# Where does the sorting/per-page logic belong in Yii2 based application?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a controller in Yii2 that displays a product catalog as a list of products. The product catalog has a control (select) to set sorting (popularity, price, etc) and entries per page (12, 24, etc).

There are several pieces of logic and I'm trying to put them in the correct layers:

1. List of possible sorting columns and list of possible per-page values
2. Default sorting column and default per-page value
3. Getting the parameters from the request (i.e. $_GET['sort']), falling back to default values if request is empty

In Yii2 there's actually a View object, so maybe some of this needs to go into it?

Comment: For those who do not know, you might want to spell out Model, View, and Controller.

Comment: Sorting would best be handled by the instance which represents a collection of domain objects (that within the model layer), since "order" is a state, which applies to the business logic. As for pagination - it's part of UI logic. And UI logic is managed by the view instances (either directly or via presentation objects). Of course that only applies to MVC, but **Yii is not implementing MVC**.

Comment: Not implementing MVC, you say? At least Yii2 is closer to MVC than Yii1. Still, this is pretty much a holywar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Yii2 the ModelNameSearch.php takes care of this. This is how I set it all up (not exactly but this is the simple version):

In the controller

```
/**
 * Sets the pagination for the list
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionPagination()
{
    TagSearch::setPerPage(Yii::$app->request->queryParams['records']);
    $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

In TagSearch

```
    public function setPerPage($recordPerPage)
    {
        Yii::$app->session->set(self::className() . 'Pagination', $recordPerPage);
    }

    public function getPerPage()
    {
        return Yii::$app->session->get(self::className() . 'Pagination', 25),
    }

.....................
    public function search($params)
    {
..............................
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => self::getPerPage()
            ],
        ]);
......................
}
```

In the view feel free to do a

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('pagination', TagSearch::getPerPage(), ['10' => '10 per page', '25' => '25 per page', '50' => '50 per page', '100' => '100 per page'], ['class' => "form-control input-sm pagination", 'data-change'=> Url::toRoute('pagination')]) ?>
```

and add a

```
$('select.pagination').on('change', function() {
    document.location.href = $(this).attr('data-change') + '?records=' + $(this).val();
});
```

I need to review the naming of the variables myself, there might be errors in the code (i wrote it copy pasting and changing) above but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Yii2 and I didn't realize that unlike Yii1 there can be a separate model for the search form (and that's what pagination and sorting are all about - they are search parameters). Gii actually produces this model, I just missed it somehow.